# Is there a way to exclude paths within docs directory in docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I want to exclude a subfolder from the `docs/` directory from generating doc pages. [`customDocsPath`](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config#customdocspath-string) is a related option but it's a string. Is there by any chance some undocumented option that accepts something like a glob pattern?

Comment: Hey Elian, Docusaurus maintainer here. In V1 there's no such option, but I believe if you don't add that doc to `sidebars.json` it shouldn't matter? Could you elaborate on your use case here?

Comment: Hey Yangshun thanks for answer! It was a case of some markdown files only being used programatically, so they don't make sense when published as pages (even if not added to `sidebars.json` people can still reach them say from google). Anyway, moving them out of `docs/` is easy enough in most cases, that's why I asked here just in case there was some option I didn't know of, rather than opening an issue with a new option proposal (I dont think one is needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To formally answer your question, no there isn't an option to do so in Docusaurus V1.

It's unlikely that we will add this into V1 but we would be happy to support that functionality in V2 and add a `draft` option in the front matter so that it would show up during development but not the production build.

Comment: > ... no there isn't an option to do so.

The leading statement should perhaps be amended to add "in V1."
In Docusaurus V2, as mentioned by @1natsu below and documented on Docusaurus's [plugin-content-blog](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-blog) and [plugin-content-doc](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs) pages, the `exclude` attribute can be used to specify an array of path glob patterns that should be excluded from the doc/blog generation process.

Comment: @OmairInam thanks for flagging. In future you can feel free to edit the answers as well, Stack Overflow encourages that :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to exclude it by specifying the configuration of the `@docusaurus/preset-classic (@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs)` plugin.

https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs

```
presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          exclude: ['**/any/dir/**'],
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```

I tested it with `v2beta.9`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to your `ducusaurus.config.file` and add and set on presets/docs the `routeBasePath: '/'`

```
  presets: [
     [
          'classic',
          /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
          ({
            docs: {
              routeBasePath: '/',
```

more info: https://docusaurus.io/docs/advanced/routing

Comment: is quite an old post, but I haven't seen an answer in Stackoverflow